# Windows 10 combine home/share/view menu

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Its quick simple, in Windows 10 you have folder views like `home/share/view/play/etc`

I have big enough monitors that I can combine these and have them displayed at once. It drives me insane having to click those all of the time.

I want to combine them all.[image]

Comment: you can disable the ribbon with this tool: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-117/ and look if this is better for you

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I actually like the ribbon. I just need to combine them!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't...

That is simply not a feature of Windows 10.

Comment: They need to add it :(

Comment: @JamieHutber That would be a nice customization feature. I am not sure if you know this or not but if you hover your mouse over the ribbon, you can use your scroll wheel to easily navigate between tabs. Same is true for Microsoft Office.

Comment: wohoooo!!!! I didn't know that but thats nice! :D